# What will happen, when Azure sends the batch of message to service bus if contains more than 256KB?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, sendmessage, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to send the batch of messages to the service bus topic. I don't know the message size of the batch.

As per the documentation, For the standard tier will allow only 256kb.

If a batch of a message contains more than the size, How should we handle that?

Is there any other inbuilt functionality to handle that?

Please suggest the approaches?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SDK (.Net for example) to send the batch and the batch size exceeds the limit (256KB), the SDK won't even add the culprit messages to the batch and would handle it on the client side only ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme-pre#send-and-receive-a-batch-of-messages)).

If you are not using the SDK and dealing with the Service Bus directly (e.g. implementing AMQP yourself or using the REST API), you will get an error from Service Bus itself. I believe the status code would be 403 (Quota exceeded or message too large ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch#response-codes)).